# Two very similar solutions to a differential equation through two different methods

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In our differential equation class, we learned of two methods to solve elementary differential equations: integration factors and seperation.

We had to solve the differential equation (k is a constant): $$\frac{dS}{dt} = 0.045S - k$$

**Using Seperation:**
$$\frac{dS}{0.045S-k} = dt$$
$$\int \frac{dS}{0.045S-k} = \int dt$$
$$\ln(0.045S-k) = t + C$$
$$0.045S-k = e^{t+C}$$
$$S = \frac{e^{t+C} + k}{0.045}$$

**Using Integrating Factors:**
$$\frac{dS}{dt} - 0.045S =-k$$
$$\mu = e^{\int -0.045*dt} = e^{-0.045t}$$
$$e^{-0.045t}*\frac{dS}{dt} - 0.045S*e^{-0.045t} = -ke^{-0.045t}$$
$$\int\left( e^{-0.045t}*\frac{dS}{dt} - 0.045S*e^{-0.045t} \right)dt= \int-ke^{-0.045t} dt$$
$$S*e^{-0.045t} = \frac{k*e^{-0.045t}}{0.045} + C$$
$$S = \frac{\frac{k*e^{-0.045t}}{0.045} + C}{e^{-0.045t}}$$

Now these two equations are completely different, why?

Comment: @kimchi editing is appreciated but please do not do many non-essential edits of old questions at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In short they are not different, you can convert one into other, just the values of constants changes.
They both are of the form $\large \displaystyle \alpha e^{0.045t}+22.2222k$.
Just to make sure your this step is wrong:
$$\int \frac{dS}{0.045S-k} = \int dt\implies\color{red}{\frac1{0.045}}\ln(0.045S-k) = t + C\implies\ln(0.045S-k)=0.045t+C'$$

Comment: @ViswaIyer see edit

Answer (score 0):

1) Using separation of variables, you have

$\int \frac{dS}{0.045S-k} = \int dt$ so $\frac{1}{.045}\int\frac{.045}{.045S-k}dS=\int dt\implies\frac{1}{.045}\ln(.045S-k)=t+C$, so

$\ln(.045S-k)=.045t+D\implies .045S-k=e^{.045t+D}\implies.045S-k=e^{D}e^{.045t}=Ae^{.045t}$ and

$.045S=Ae^{.045t}+k\implies S=\frac{Ae^{.045t}+k}{.045}=Be^{.045t}+c$ $\;\;\;$(where $B=\frac{A}{.045}$ and $c=\frac{k}{.045}$).

2) Using an integrating factor and the fact that the DE is linear,

you obtained $Se^{-.045t}=\frac{ke^{-.045t}}{.045}+C$, so $S=e^{.045t}\left(\frac{ke^{-.045t}}{.045}+C\right)=\frac{k}{.045}+Ce^{.045t}=Ce^{.045t}+D$

(where $D=\frac{k}{.045}$); $\;\;\;$so the two solutions are equivalent.